# Changing App language after Login - Android

Tags: android, rest

I'm having an issue with my android project. I'm trying to set the language on app start with the value I'm getting from my REST Request.
Here's my Code from the Controller class:

```
public void onResponse(Call<UserProfile> call, Response<UserProfile> response) {
            UserProfile userProfile = response.body();
            OMSActivity.initLanguage(userProfile);
        }
```

Here's my Code from the Activity class:

```
public void changeLang(Context v, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.setLocale(locale);
    v.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, v.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}

public void initLanguage(UserProfile userProfile) {
    switch(userProfile.getLanguage()) {
        case "en": changeLang(this,"en"); break;
        case "de": changeLang(this, "de"); break;
    }

}
```

The request is successful and the response is filled with the language string, but somehow, the language doesn't get changed.

Here's the onCreate of the Activity class:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.omsController = new omsController(this);
omsController.getUserProfile();
setContentView(R.layout.activity_oms);
```

In another activity, the language can be changed on Button Click. Surprisingly, it works there fine.

Comment: Your api may be asynchronous and therefore layout would be loaded before api response and hence language change did not reflect.

Comment: @DB377 even if i just try changeLang("de") in my onCreate it doesn't work, something might be wrong with my changeLang method.